# Using an Odata API when a Foreign Key relationship is null in the database, a SqlNullValueException: Data is Null Exception is thrown

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, odata

I am trying to create a relationship between two entities and found that when the foreign key is null in the database, EF Core throws a  `SqlNullValueException: Data is Null` exception.

Here is the primary entity (`Person` table):

```
[Key]
public int PersonId { get; set; }
public int? StaffId { get; set; }

public virtual StaffView? StaffView { get; set; }
```

And this is the related entity (`Staff` table):

```
[Key]
public int StaffId { get; set; }
public int? PersonId { get; set; }

public virtual PersonView? PersonView { get; set; }
```

Here is my `DbContext` class:

```
public virtual DbSet<PersonView>? PersonViews { get; set; } = null!;
public virtual DbSet<StaffView> StaffViews { get; set; } = null!;

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonView>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Persons", "Person");
    entity.Property(e => e.PersonId).HasColumnName("Person_ID").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    entity.HasKey(e => e.PersonId);

    entity.Property(e => e.StaffId).HasColumnName("Staff_ID");

    entity.HasOne(a => a.StaffView)
        .WithOne(b => b.PersonView)
        .HasPrincipalKey<PersonView>(b => b.StaffId)
        .HasForeignKey<StaffView>(b => b.StaffId)
        .IsRequired(false);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<StaffView>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Staff", "Person");
    entity.Property(e => e.StaffId).HasColumnName("Staff_ID").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    entity.HasKey(e => e.StaffId);
    entity.Property(e => e.PersonId).HasColumnName("Person_ID");
});
```

EDM entry (in `Program.cs`):

```
builder.EntitySet<PersonView>("OViewPersons");
```

Controller:

```
public class OViewPersonsController : ODataController
{
    private readonly ViewContext? _context;
    
    public OViewPersonsController(ViewContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 6)]
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<PersonView>> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<PersonView> queryResults = _context.PersonViews
                                                          .Include(sta => sta.StaffView);
            return Ok(queryResults);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Database schema:

```
[Person].[Persons]
    [Person_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    [Staff_ID] [int] NULL

[Person].[Staff]
    [Staff_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    [Person_ID] [int] NULL
```

When the `Staff ID` in the `Persons` table is Null:

```
Person_Id   Staff_Id
--------------------
397748      NULL
```

The following exception is thrown:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'GatewayApi.DbContexts.GatewayApiContext'.
> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
> at lambda_method321(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()

Software used and its versions:

- VS 2022 - Version 17.3.6
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore                    {6.0.10} GatewayApi
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer          {6.0.10} GatewayApi
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore                           {6.4.0}  GatewayApi
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson          {6.0.10} GatewayApi
- System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager        {6.0.1}  GatewayApi
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools              {6.0.10} GatewayApi
- Twilio                                           {5.81.0} GatewayApi
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design {6.0.10} GatewayApi
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData                       {8.0.11} GatewayApi

I need a result set that does not error and allows nulls in foreign key fields.

I have tried a number of solutions but nothing seems to work

I added "Foreign Key" annotations in the model classes:

```
[ForeignKey("StaffView")]
public int? StaffId { get; set; }
```

and

```
[ForeignKey("StaffId")]
public virtual StaffView? StaffView { get; set; }
```

I tried with and without the `.IsRequired(false)` in the `DbContext`.

I tried various combinations of identifying all of the different parameters as null or not null

```
public int? StaffId { get; set; }
```

and

```
public int StaffId { get; set; }
```

I tried disabling Nullable in the Project Build configuration.

I tried changing the `Staff_ID` in the `Person` table from nullable to not nullable.

I have searched the net and tried a bunch of other suggestions but can not remember them all.

I have searched far and wide and believe it is related to the Int32 foreign key being null in the primary entity. I found a lot of answers that are related to annotating or marking the parameters as null but haven't been successful in finding a solution related to nulls in the foreign key database field.

I have tried to be a detailed as possible but if I missed something, please let me know.

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now and I just can not seem to get it to work as I expect.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have tried too many different conflicting solutions at the same time, when you do this it is ambiguous as to which configuration or attribute is the cause when things go wrong.

Comment: Is the relationship supposed to be 1:1 between Staff and Person? You have defined both the `Staff` _and_ the `Person` tables as the principals... if that is your intent then the setup is wrong, but I need to know in plain terms which is the principal and which is the dependant. Only the dependant table would have the ID for the _principal_. The principal class will have a collection property that contains the dependants. Even if that collection only ever has a single item in it.

Comment: The Primary entity should be Person and should have a 1 Person entity to 0 or 1 Staff entity relationship.  I thought by setting up these two entities this way it would create a bi-directional relationship so I could access the relationship from both entities.  Is this correct?   I just tried removing the relationship from the Staff entity and only have one Principal dependency on the Person entity and unfortunately, it is still throwing the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we think in terms of real world object hierarchies, a `Staff` member *is a* `Person`, but not all people are `Staff` members, so *1 Person entity to 0 or 1 Staff* makes sense. In EF though, the reciprocal of that relationship is
actually *1 Staff : many Persons*. If you need to deliberately constrain the *many Persons* to only 1, then that is easier to achieve by implementing a unique constraint on the *Staff* table.

- This is not the only way to achieve this type of relationship, but in EF it is a lot easier both in terms of configuration and longer term management.

> **NOTE:** In this solution we are only exploring the EF schema constraints, not OData controller or query logic was presented. Having the EF schema correct is only the first step, how you assign the related objects can still have an affect that we should explore

We don't even need to use fluent configuration for this simple setup, we can use attribute notation:

```
[Table("Persons", Schema = "Person")]
public class PersonView
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Person_ID")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<StaffView> StaffViews { get; set; } 
        = new HashSet<StaffView>();
}

[Table("Staff", Schema = "Person")]
public class StaffView
{
    [Key]  
    [Column("Staff_ID")]
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("Person_ID")]
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual PersonView? PersonView { get; set; }
}
```

This still gives you navigation property access to the `Staff` from the `Person`. This type of relationship clearly defines `Person` as the principal and `Staff' as the dependant.

See this Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dZ3kvq

If your relationship needs to be 1:0-1 then EF handles this through inheritance, re-using the `PersonId` as the primary key of the `StaffView`. To do this you are effectively implementing *Table-Per-Type* (TPT) hierarchy, which works well in .Net 6 but you do not *assign* the related entities, like what you are doing here.

Attribute notation saves a lot of time and allows you to manage key database schema metadata with your data models. Data annotations are processed by the EF ModuleBuilder using built in *and customisable* conventions into the configuration for the model.

You can choose to override the *standard* implementations using *fluent* configuration, if you do not use data annotations then the built in conventions will still pickup a lot of the configuration but it relies on the naming convention of your properties and keys to match these conventions. If you are not using Attribute notation then you should express any key structural elements like foreign keys, explicitly in your *fluent configuration*.

So if you do not want to use Attribute notation, the first-principals approach in *fluent configuration* looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonView>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("Persons", "Person");
        entity.Property(e => e.PersonId).HasColumnName("Person_ID").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.HasKey(e => e.PersonId);

        entity.HasMany(person => person.StaffViews)
            .WithOne(staff => staff.PersonView)
            .HasPrincipalKey(person => person.PersonId)
            .HasForeignKey(staff => staff.PersonId)
            .IsRequired(false);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<StaffView>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("Staff", "Person");
        entity.Property(e => e.StaffId).HasColumnName("Staff_ID").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.HasKey(e => e.StaffId);
        
        entity.Property(e => e.PersonId).HasColumnName("Person_ID");
    });
}
```

entity. Property/dotnetfiddle.net/hEjwqK

The fiddles there demonstrate assigning the relationship using the navigation property to link the objects:

```
// Using first, because there is only one of each entity in this DB
var person = context2.PersonViews.First();
var staff = context2.StaffViews.First();
staff. Person = person;
context2.SaveChanges();
```

However you could use the FK `PersonId` to do this directly without the object link:

```
// Using first, because there is only one of each entity in this DB
var person = context2.PersonViews.First();
var staff = context2.StaffViews.First();
staff.PersonId = person.PersonId;
context2.SaveChanges();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ohvv5q

How an OData context behaves with this will depend on how you have setup your OData Model and how you are querying the service to assign the keys. As long as you stick to the *convention* of representing the `1:0-1` relationship using the `1:Many` structure in EF, the default OData conventional model builder should setup the required elements for this to work in OData.

---

#### Regarding Fluent Configuration

Using fluent configuration over annotations is a one of those long running conflicts between developers, just like light mode vs dark mode.

My personal bias is to use Data annotations, and conventions, and to minimise any *fluent* configuration in a code base. It con significantly reduces the management overheads of changes to the schema over time but also makes the database metadata, relationships and indexes discoverable through the model. For larger schemas or larger teams this can significantly reduce negative time spent by new (and seasoned) developers who haven't fully memorised the data schema and don't want to traverse the fluent scripts to determine if indexes or relationships have been applied or what relationships might exist at all for an individual entity.

- I do not see any value in separating the DB configuration from the model, especially when you are using OData, the OData conventional model builder uses many of the same data annotations to build it's model so in an *OData* service project there is even more value in adopting the *Attribute Notation* as the primary configuration for you data schema.
- I rate knowing at a glance that a particular property name or table name in the model has been overridden with a different name or data type in the database of greater importance than sticking to theoretical practices that separate the data schema from the actual database schema too much ;)

In many online tutorials *fluent* configuration is used because it is visually explicit to the reader and it overrides many previous configurations or annotations which makes it more likely that your config will be obeyed by the reader's code base when they cut'n'paste the content. Do not confuse this as *best practice* or the *more current* way to configure EF, both methodologies are *current* and relevant.

Comment: I resolved this by removing the Fluent assignments and implemented annotations as described above.  Thank you Chris!

Comment: Actually this is still a problem.  I ran into a lot of problems using Annotations so I went back to Fluent.  It is my understanding, based on researching on the web, that Fluent has more functionality than using Annotations and is a more current way to define navigational relationships.  That being said, I am still running into the problem with null values in the Principal key field of the relationship.  If I change the null to a 0, it starts working.  But is the key field in the db is null, the error occurs.

Comment: Did you remove `StaffId` from `PersonView`? I'll add the same example using fluent configuration. Annotations are processed by the in-built conventions. Using _fluent_ overrides any annotations. Annotations and the default conventions exists to save time and maintenance effort. Fluent config does have more functionality but it disassociates the model definition from the configuration, so we usually reserve fluent config for options that are hard to configure otherwise. In this case only 4 annotations are required, that's 4 lines of code to manage, instead of many more in configuration.

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for the perspective.  I am trying to overcome an issue and looking for a solution.  My database is much larger than what I am showing, as I am sure you could have guessed, and when I was using Annotations, I ran into some problems with duplicate relation assignments.  I am sure I could have overcome them but for what its worth, I decided to go back to Fluent.  I truly do not understand why a Principal Key in the Primary entity can not be null when there is nothing for it to link to.  Furthermore, why does adding a 0 prevent the error?  BTW, I did not remove the staff id.

Comment: Ah ha, after reading your post again, I missed the fact that using one to one versus one to many could have been the issue.  This statement helped me "How an OData context behaves with this will depend on how you have setup your OData Model and how you are querying the service to assign the keys. As long as you stick to the convention of representing the 1:0-1 relationship using the 1:Many structure in EF, the default OData conventional model builder should setup the required elements for this to work in OData."  Thanks again Chris!

Comment: Kind of fundamental,  One to One = One to Always One, One to Many = One to Zero, One or More.   I know this but got stuck thinking One to One could be configured to One to Zero or One.

Comment: One to One in EF and OData has other structural implications and is best achieved using inheritance, otherwise you will have to use custom logic to correctly retrieve the objects and assign the keys, OData won't figure it out on its own. Either way 1:0-1 isn't normally managed in the database by having a FK in both tables like you have done, one of the tables MUST be the principal, remove the FK from that table. There is no value is having the reverse FK back, it just adds an extra field that you have to index and manage.

Comment: I didn't feel right about using One to Many like this for a while, but its a pragmatic approach that will save you a lot of time throughout the lifetime of the application. You can easily add a unique constraint to the dependant table to prevent multiple entries, so keeping it at 1:0-1. If you are happy to change the structure of the existing DB to true 1:0-1 then it can be done, but you end up with `PersonId` as the _PK_ in both tables and no separate _FK_, but then you cannot create a `Staff` without having `Person`, You _extend_ an existing `Person` to become a `Staff`.